# Create dependencies between variables in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have Grafana dashboard which shows logs. I created some variables [variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NXPE.png)

How can I define the dependences between them in order to when I select one namespace in Namespace area (variable), Grafana shows only containers in selected namespace (which satisfy only selected namespace)

[Namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqPkN.png)
[All containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Im1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some relevant log and change the label_values to something like this:

`label_values(kube_pod_container_info{namespace="$namespace"}, container)`

the above line will make the container filter to depend on the namespace